# Writing data to resized hdf5 dataset fails in surprising ways

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to create a dataset which I don't know the full size of initially.

I create my dataset with the following properties.

```py
file['data'].create_dataset(
   name='test', shape=(10, len(arr1)), 
   maxshape=(10, None), dtype=float,
   scaleoffset=3, chunks=True, 
   compression='gzip', compression_opts=4, fillvalue=np.nan)
```

where the final dimension in shape is the dimension I need to expand (initial shape given by first input).

When I resize the dataset for the arr2, everything works fine, but when I try to extend it to the much larger size for arr3, things start to behave strangely.

If I incrementally resize and write each array one after the other, the contents of the dataset becomes corrupted, and values outside of the first arrays length (`arr1`), in this case 100, are written to the fill value (`nan`), while the first 100 values are stored correctly. Note that this doesn't happen when resizing and writing `arr2`, this will correctly write all values of `arr2`, while extending the first entry with `nan`.

I've also tried manually increasing the chunk size, but this fails at using the correct fill value (defaults to 0, rather than `nan`) when I write smaller arrays, and unless the chunk size is explicitly larger than the largest array, the largest array is still truncated to the fill value outside of the chunk size.

```py
arr1 = np.arange(0, 100, step=1, dtype=float)
arr2 = np.arange(0, 233, step=1, dtype=float)
arr3 = np.arange(0, 50000, step=1, dtype=float)

file = h5py.File(my_data_file, 'w')
file.create_group('data')
file['data'].create_dataset(
   name='test', shape=(10, len(arr1)), 
   maxshape=(10, None), dtype=float,
   scaleoffset=3, chunks=True, 
   compression='gzip', compression_opts=4, fillvalue=np.nan)

file['data']['test'][0, :len(arr1)] = arr1
try:
    file['data']['test'][1, :len(arr2)] = arr2
except TypeError as e:
    print('New data too large for old dataset, resizing')
    file['data']['test'].resize((10, len(arr2)))
    file['data']['test'][1, :len(arr2)] = arr2
```

If I stop here, everything looks as expected, but the main problem arises when I run the following code.

```py
try:
    file['data']['test'][2, :len(arr3)] = arr3
except TypeError as e:
    print('New data too large for old dataset, resizing')
    file['data']['test'].resize((10, len(arr3)))
    file['data']['test'][2, :len(arr3)] = arr3
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests to diagnose. First I ran 3 separate steps, and I see different behavior than you described.
**Test 1: arr1 only**
Only add `arr1` to row 0 and close the file:
Row 0 has correct `arr1` values and rows 1-9 are filled with `0.0`, not `NaN`.
**Test 2: arr1 & arr2**
Add `arr1` to row 0, resize, then add `arr2` to row 1, and close the file:
For Columns 0-99: Rows 0 and 1 are filled, and rows 2-9 are filled with 0.0, not `NaN`. Columns 100+ are all `=NaN`, FOR ALL ROWS. Note that `arr2` values > 99 are not in the file.
**Test 3: arr1, arr2, arr3**
Loads all 3 arrays following process above:
Similar results to Test 2: For Columns 0-99: Rows 0,1,2 are filled, and rows 3-9 are filled with 0.0, not `NaN`. Columns 100+ are all `=NaN`, FOR ALL ROWS. Note that `arr2` and `arr3` values > 99 are not in the file.

I then reran **Test 3** after modifying `create_dataset()`; removing the following arguments: `scaleoffset=3, chunks=True, compression='gzip', compression_opts=4`.
The resulting HDF5 file looks exactly as expected, with `NaN` everywhere data wasn't added (in Row 0, Columns 100+; Row 1, Columns 233+, and all columns in rows 3-9). See modified call below:

```
h5f['data'].create_dataset(
   name='test', shape=(10, len(arr1)), 
   maxshape=(10, None), dtype=float, fillvalue=np.nan)
```

I don't know enough about the 4 deleted parameters to explain why this works -- only that it does.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, looking into the documentation further it appears that the `scaleoffset` option does not work for special floating type values (i.e. `Inf` and `NaN`). I believe when the data is being 'chunked' it converts `NaN` to 0, although it's still not clear why not all column values (i.e. `arr2` and `arr3` values > 99) are being stored correctly.

Comment: Another resource is the [h5py Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h5py). The h5py developers respond to some of the posts.